# htaccess mod rewrite with smf forum url not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a problem with trying to redirect urls in a htaccess file

I am trying to redirect from this url  below, (u=6 will be random numbers)

index.php?action=profile;u=6

to

index.php?action=pm

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^index.php?action=profile;u=/([^/]*)$ index.php?action=pm
```

I have tried lots of different varations but I can not seem to get it to work

I have the app installed under the directory

/messages

I tried making all the changes to the htaccess file in both the /root and /messages directory, but to no aval, any help would be grateful, thanks in advance for your time

Comment: two questions. Is the "u" a standard url parameter or not? Where does the "m" come from?

Comment: hello the u is users, ie u=3 or u=234 etc and on -  action=pm, this is a link to the private messages system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=profile;u=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.php?action=pm [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

RewriteRule ^index.php\?action=profile;u=([0-9])+$ index.php?action=pm